# Forms app wont accept my SQL table column with usernames, but it will accept the password

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, authentication

I'm creating a forms application which needs a login function. I have set up the MySqL connection and have applied it to my form. It does answer to my to responses, giving me a respons with a pass or no pass, BUT this is only when I ask for it to only match the input with passwords in the database. I cannot get it to match both the usernames and the passwords, even though I seem to have configurated my table as it should be. I've got 3 columns with ID, username(brugernavn) and password.
I can get it to accept both credentials if I match the ID's with the right password, fx `SELECT * FROM bruger WHERE password =@pass AND id=@usn`

I'm still very new to programming so if I'm confused please let me know.
Is anyone able to help?

I've tried to change my parameters to something else, but that didnt do the trick. There didnt seem to be a problem with the actual table, as it could acces my information about the passwords and the ID's, so I tried changing some values and stuff from the username column, but it did no good. I have both the username and password using varchar(100) and the ID is using INT(11) as a primary.

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=bruger");       

    public void openConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
    public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }


private void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
        DB db = new DB();
        string username = textBoxBrugernavn.Text;
        string password = textBoxPassword.Text;
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bruger WHERE password =@pass AND brugernavn =@usn", db.GetConnection());
        command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
        command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);          
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO");
        }
```

I was hoping this would let me run my forms apps and then let me login with already created users in my database. This however is not the case, as I am unable to match these two informations in the application.

Comment: Plain text passwords are a bad idea. See what winform/C# offers in terms of a framework to avoid them.

Comment: Im not too worried about that since its a school project

Comment: I am worried if code like this passes, and that student goes on to implement real application, in the same defective way, that I might end up using it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep you data objects local. Then you can be sure they are closed and disposed. The using blocks take care of that even if there is an error. Since we only need one piece of data (the count) we can use ExecuteScalar which returns the first column of the first row in the result set. Of course, in a real application, you would never store passwords as plain text. They would be salted and hashed.

```
    private void Loginbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int64 RecordCount = 0;
        using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=bruger"))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM bruger WHERE password =@pass AND brugernavn =@usn", cn))
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@usn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxBrugernavn.Text;
                command.Parameters.Add("@pass", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPassword.Text;
                cn.Open();
                RecordCount = (Int64)command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        if (RecordCount > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("YES");
            //Add code to proceed to your next form
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO");
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I try to run this I get the error System.InvalidCastException

Comment: Hum, Count(*) should always return an integer. Just found out it returns BigInt. Let's try Int64. I have edited my answer to change datatype of RecordCount and cast of (Int64)

Comment: I doesnt give me the error anymore, but it didnt fix the problem with not being able to logon :/ Seems it must be a problem with my database?